# Changing my geometry dash username once it has already been changed once

Tags: geometry-dash

So I had my geometry dash name as the same as my YouTube channel, then I changed my YouTube channel name. So I changed my gd name. But then I created a new YouTube channel, and I want to name it after that, but I have already changed it once. So is there a way I can change my name from there?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait about a month to be able to change your username again.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the database will glitch out and allow you to change it again. This happened to me and I changed my name again.

Answer (score -2):

You have to wait a month in order to be able to change it again.

Comment: This repeats the info from [user166027’s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/285150/181240)

Answer (score -4):

No. It's impossible to change your name a second time, emphasis on **impossible**.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score -5):

Try these 2 things:

1. Get out of geometry dash, and relog. It ***MIGHT*** change.
2. If your name is **GOLD...** you need to follow these steps: (*Go to:       settings -> account -> save -> go **back** -> click UNLINK. Go to account. Make a account. Make EVERYTHING the same except the things you wanna change. DONE.*)

Comment: For point 1 - That will never happen. | For point 2 - That'll wipe your saves. (Backing up the folder in `%localappdata%` will have you "logged" back into the account; profile name still locked, but credentials are invalid for cloud functions).